# Can you combine admin and console war into a single ear file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

You have to deploy admin and console war on the same cluster so can you combine admin and console war files into a single ear file and deploy it manually on WebSphere. Is this supported configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supported since ear file is only an another type of packaging to deploy applications in an application server. And in fact when you deploy a war file in WebSphere the resulting installed app is an ear file.
ApplicationCenter for example is shipped with 2 war files for the console and the admin services but also with an ear file containing both (it is also the case for Analytics).